# Data confidentiality in R

Tags: r

I'm considering using R in my work. Primarily I am interested in ggplot2, dplyr and tidyr, probably using the RStudio environment.

I deal with a lot of sensitive educational data, such as names, dates of birth etc and could only only use R at work if I knew the data were safe.

Will my data be kept private/confidential or is it shared in any way?

Comment: It's not shared with anybody unless you do it by yourself . You have the full control over your data confidentiality .

Comment: Why the down-votes? This is a perfectly reasonable question on a programming tool.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik question boils down to: "I use R, is my data safe?", it is too broad/opinion based.

Answer (score 3):

By default, data or code is not shared to the outside world. This may not hold for cases including but not confined to:

- when you are using (online) version control
- if you are pushing a report to RPubs repository
- using R on a server, which may be accessible to third parties